# ¿Puedo usar un Eval() en el ItemCommand de un ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lo que quiero hacer es un botón que me edite un dato por *SQL*, ya eso lo tengo, pero necesito el *ID* de la fila a editar (que la extraigo con el `Eval("id")` del `listview1`).

Tengo un `ListView` que dentro del `ItemTemplate` hay un botón (`btnSeguir`) con la propiedad `commandName = "seguir"`.

El `listview`:

```
<asp:ListView
    ID="ListView1"
    runat="server"
    OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
>
```

Botón en `ItemTemplate` de `listview1`:

```
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="btnSeguir"
    CommandName="seguir"
    runat="server"
><%# siguiendo() %></asp:LinkButton>
```

En el `ListView1_ItemCommand` quiero llamar la función `Eval("id")` de `ListView1`:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "seguir")
    {
        ConsultasSQL c = new ConsultasSQL("XConnectionString");
        c.seguir(Eval("id")+"", Session["usrid"].ToString());
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto, al dar al botón btnSeguir me sale este error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Los métodos de enlace de datos como Eval(), XPath() y Bind() sólo se pueden utilizar en el contexto de un control de enlace de datos.'

Lo extraño es que me funciona el método `siguiendo()` del boton, que también llama a `Eval("id")` y sí me extrae el dato, pero en el `itemCommand` no.

¿Cómo soluciono esto? ¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado. Y la respuesta es No porque ItemCommand es un metodo protected. Lo solucioné por mi cuenta al descubrir la propiedad CommandArgument que la utilice en el boton y en el ItemCommand en vez de usar Eval("id") use e.CommandArgument

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSeguir" CommandName="seguir" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server"><%# siguiendo() %></asp:LinkButton>
```

---

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "seguir")
    {
        ConsultasSQL c = new ConsultasSQL("XConnectionString");
        c.seguir(e.CommandArgument+"", Session["usrid"].ToString());
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```